# How to hide the custom post from URL from the google search?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, google-search, yoast

I am using the below code for the custom post and it's working.

I have a small issue with searching on Google, I search my domain on google and I found the below output.

**Note: This is just an example for the reference image.**

[image]

You can see in the screenshot, I am getting the URL `https://www.example.com/heroslider`.

My issue is, I don't want to show that URL in the google search. Because it's showing my all the posts which I created.
I have added some limited posts on my home and I have to redirect the user from the home page only.

Is there any way to stop?

I am using the Yoast plugin for SEO.

```
// Register Custom Post Type heroslider
function create_heroslider_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'herosliders', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'heroslider', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'herosliders', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'heroslider', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        'archives' => __( 'heroslider Archives', 'textdomain' ),
        'attributes' => __( 'heroslider Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent heroslider:', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All herosliders', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_items' => __( 'View herosliders', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list' => __( 'herosliders list', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'herosliders list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter herosliders list', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'heroslider', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'heroslider', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'create_heroslider_cpt', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code snippet can be useful.

```
function add_meta_tags()
{
    
    if ('heroslider' == get_post_type()) {
        echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex">';
        echo '<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_tags', 2);
```

OR

[wordify.com/blog/wordpress/wordpress-robots-txt-functions-and-rules](https://wordify.com/blog/wordpress/wordpress-robots-txt-functions-and-rules)